# PhpStorm freeze on mac

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 8.02. On Windows, it's ok, but on my mac, it's freeze 10 seconds when I click on a file for exemple (or even when I click on some menu).

I updated java JRE, but nothing change.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing the CPU snapshots (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems) and thread dumps (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667-Getting-a-thread-dump-when-IDE-hangs-and-does) taken when the IDE 'freezes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It was a plugin (git-flow plugin). When I disabled it, all was fine.